# Flickering during sprite sheet animation

Tags: c++, sfml

I am animating my sprite which looks like this:

[image]

I made a variable which increments by 64 every time i press W, as each sprite is 64 x 64, it works however there is blinking, here is my code. It is in the draw method by the way.

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)){
    animator += 64;
}
else{
    animator = 0;
}


if (animator > 512){
    animator = 0;
}
playerSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, animator, 64, 64));
window.draw(playerSprite);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I don't know that library, but I'd guess that the blinking problem could be somehow related to a lack of backbuffering or doublebuffering at some point. This is quite common problem with almost all libraries, especially when you try to "just draw" without getting too much in the stage rendering details. Anyways, I looked a bit and found many resources about "SFML sprite sheet animation" [ie. here](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6102.0) - I think this is what you are going after.

Comment: On some forums, people even dropped some ready to use classes like 'AnimatedSprite'. I don't suggest you to get and use them - but you could look into them and check how they are preloading the images ans switching between the frames. Btw. If I'm right about backbuffering, then the cause may be the set-and-draw, which might cause drawing out-of-sync with the screen buffer, especially worth checking if you've got the 'isKeyPressed' in the same logical part of code. In 99% of cases redrawing on a keypress is not a good idea. But, again, that's guessing, I don't know anything about that library.

Comment: BTW. welcome to StackOverflow! :) didn't I saw you at 2K by chance? You might recognize the 'que' :)

Comment: Yeah that was my other question, I'll mark it as solved! I'll try your suggestions out later! Thanks for the advice. Everyone here is very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't implement the frame's change this way : the change here is dependent of the framerate and not of the elapsed time.

You should have a timer and change the frame, each [FRAME_DELAY] time.
For example, each 200 ms.